# Exim4 how to relay some recipients to another server

Tags: email-server, exim

I have a domain managed by two servers, they have different mailboxes but the same domain.

How can I set Exim to forward some recipient email to the second server?
I checked many tutorial but they always forward to another email address, but I cannot find how to insert a list of recipient to be handled by an second server.

Comment: What is the goal, why two servers? Are you trying to scale out mail receipt, or storage, or both?

Comment: This feature called address rewriting  https://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch-address_rewriting.html more specific - envelop address rewriting